# Cannot read property 'intent' of undefined

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to make a conversational chatbot using Dialogflow. Below this code is supposed to identify the intent of the entered sentence and return appropriate answer from the db. But my code is throwing "Cannot read property intent of undefined", can someone tell me what might cause this? Thank you in advance!

```
 exports.foodFunction = async (req, res) => {
  const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
  const CONNECTION_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

  // initate a connection to the deployed mongodb cluster
  const client = new MongoClient(CONNECTION_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  });

  client.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      res
        .status(500)
        .send({ status: "MONGODB CONNECTION REFUSED", error: err });
    }
    const collection = client.db(process.env.DATABASE_NAME).collection("Meals");
    let intent = req.body.queryResult.intent.displayName;
    console.log(intent);
    let params = req.body.queryResult.parameters;
```

Answer (score 0):

The blunt answer is that this is caused by `req.body.queryResult` being undefined, and likely from `req.body` not having a `queryResult` attribute.

It isn't clear why this might be from your example, although a few debugging approaches come to mind:

- Log `req.body.queryResult` to confirm it's undefined.
- Log `req.body` to see what it is actually set to.
- Log `typeof req.body` to confirm if it is an object. If it is a string, then you're not decoding the JSON into an object.

I suspect that last point may be at the root of your problems. You're not showing how the `foodFunction` function is being called, so it isn't clear how `req` is created. If you're using an express-like system, however, then you may not have configured the `express.json()` middleware that is [required to generate `req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) correctly.